# access mode in mkdir() sys call linux c

Tags: c, linux, mkdir

I have a portion of code

```
if(mkdir(name, 0666/*permission*/) == -1)
            {
                        printf("ERROR");
                        return ERROR;
            }
```

The newly-created directory looks like

```
drw-rw-r-- 2 atg atg  4096 Oct  3 17:54 f,,,
```

But I wanted it to have write permissions for others, i.e. `drw-rw-rw-`.

When I try to enter the directory, using `cd`, I get

> bash: cd: f: Permission denied

If I create it with execute permissions, like this:

```
if(mkdir(name, 0777/*permission*/) == -1)
                {
                            printf("ERROR");
                            return ERROR;
                }
```

I get

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 atg atg  4096 Oct  3 18:00 f
```

I am able to enter directory with `cd`.

With

```
if(mkdir(name, 0777/*permission*/) == -1)
            {
                        printf("ERROR");
                        return ERROR;
            }
```

I get

dr-xr-xr-x 2 atg atg  4096 Oct  3 18:02 f

Why is the write permission not set?

I used chmod as

```
case RD_WRT_DATA:
                            permission = 0666;
                            break;

   if(mkdir(name, permission) == -1)
    {
                printf("ERROR");
                return ERROR;
    }

    else
    {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    if(chmod(name, permission) == -1)
    {
         printf("ERROR");
         return ERROR;

    }
    else
    {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

checked umask:

```
grep UMASK /etc/login.defs

UMASK       022
```

still permissions i get is->

```
drw-rw-r-- 2 atg atg  4096 Oct  3 18:15 f
```

---

Should I change umask? Is there any alterative without doing that?

Comment: _but the permission required is `drw-rw-rw-`_ - are you sure? That means nobody can access anything within the directory. You need `x` to access the content of a directory (if you know what is there), and `r` to list the content, but `r` without `x` is pretty much useless

Comment: You should use `perror(name);`  (instead of `printf("ERROR");`  ....) for error handling

Answer (score 2):

A directory without executable permissions cannot be listed.

In addition to setting `umask(0)`, create the directory with mode `0777`.

Answer (score 2):

The process's `umask` value is masking off the write permissions for non-owners.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask:

> In computing, umask is a command that determines the settings of a
>   mask that controls how file permissions are set for newly created
>   files. It also may refer to a function that sets the mask, or **it may
>   refer to the mask itself, which is formally known as the file mode
>   creation mask. The mask is a grouping of bits, each of which restricts
>   how its corresponding permission is set for newly created files.**

The umask value is global to a process.  Thus calling `umask()` will affect all threads running in the process, along with all child processes spawned after changing the value.

To safely ensure file or directory permissions without impacting the rest of the process, you need to explicitly set the permission with `chmod()`:

```
int rc;
mode_t mode = 0777;

rc = mkdir( name, mode );
if ( 0 == rc )
{
    rc = chmod( name, mode );
}
.
.
.
```

If you really want do change `umask()`, it's much better to set it to what you need, then *restore it afterward*:

```
mode_t old_mask = umask( 0 );
int rc = mkdir( name, 0777 );
umask( old_mask );
```

Comment: Note that changing and restoring the umask is still not safe in multithread applications, because other threads will be using the modified umask during the time in between.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
umask(0);
```

before the `mkdir`, since `umask` has an influence on the permissions of the newly created directory.

Answer (score 0):

Most linux distros use default `umask = 022`. That means when you calling `mkdir` with permissions `777`, you get permissions: `777(asked) - 022(umask) = 0755(actual)`. Actually, the `umask` is *what permissions should be removed from newly created files/dirs*, where each octal digit means:

```
0 : read, write and execute
1 : read and write
2 : read and execute
3 : read only
4 : write and execute
5 : write only
6 : execute only
7 : nothing
```

Make `umask(0)` and you will get asked permissions `777` on created dir.